# track changes in database tables

Tags: postgresql

I have a large postgresql database, and I want to track all it's tables if a change has been made.

The reason for that is that I can't know a relation between two different tables in the database.

I googled about it but I couldn't find anything helpful.

So how can I know if a change has been made to a table ?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what information you want? Are you looking for a permanent history of every `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` on every table?

Comment: @NickBarnes yes thats what I mean

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a global audit function in PostgreSQL.

It'll be possible to build one using the new [logical changeset extraction](http://rhaas.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/postgresql-now-has-logical-decoding.html) feature in 9.4, and I know some people are working on that.

In the mean time, you need to add [some form of audit trigger](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) to every table.